# How to await on the closing event of the fd assigned to loop.add_reader?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Let's consider this example code:

```
myfd = ... # my fd, can be a socket for example

def reader():
    data = myfd.recv(100)
    print("Received:", data.decode())

asyncio.get_event_loop().loop.add_reader(myfd, reader)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

My issue is the `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()` part. I would like to `await` on the closing event of myfd instead.

Comment: Note that `add_reader()` is a low-level API intended for implementors of alternative event loops. As a user of asyncio, one is supposed to use the [stream API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @user4815162342,however I don't see an alternative since stream API supports is limited to sockets and sometimes you need to go low level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
myfd = ... # my fd, can be a socket for example

conn_closed = asyncio.Event() # <-- This is the solution

def reader():
    try:
      data = myfd.recv(100)
      print("Received:", data.decode())
    except EOFError: # connection closed
      conn_closed.set()
    except Exception as e:
      print(f"Unexpected Exception: {e}")
      conn_closed.set()

asyncio.get_event_loop().loop.add_reader(myfd, reader)

await conn_closed.wait()
```